# Appending a 2d-array to a 1d-array in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have a empty numpy array now i want to append a 2d array

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([])
>>> b = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
>>> np.append(a, b)
array([1, 2, 3, 4])
```

but i want `[[[1, 2], [3, 4]]]`

Comment: Start with `a = b`, and then call `np.append(a, b, axis=0)` inside a loop

Comment: `np.append` has 2 modes.  Without `axis` it flattens everything, as you found out.  WIth an `axis` it just does a `concatenate`, requiring matching dimensions.  It seems that a lot of posters don't pay attention to the documentation of functions like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are 2 ways of concatenating an 'empty` array with a 2d array, producing a new array that looks just like the original:

```
In [123]: b = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
In [124]: b.shape
Out[124]: (2, 2)
In [125]: np.concatenate((np.zeros((2,0),int),b),axis=1)
Out[125]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
In [126]: _.shape
Out[126]: (2, 2)

In [127]: np.concatenate((np.zeros((0,2),int),b),axis=0)
Out[127]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
```

The usual rules about number of dimensions matching, and the non-joining shapes matching apply.  Also pay attention to `dtype`.

`append`, `vstack`, `hstack` fiddle with shapes, and then do `concatenate`.  It is best to understand how to use `concatenate` directly.

But one might ask, why go all this work of concatenation, only to produce a matching array?  `b.copy()` is simpler.

If this is the start of a loop, don't.  Use list append to build a list of arrays, and then concatenate once at the end.  `concatenate` takes a list of arrays.  `np.append` only takes 2 inputs, and treats them differently.  I discourage its use.

### edit

Are  you serious about wanting a 3d result as opposed to 2d?

```
In [128]: np.array([[[1, 2], [3, 4]]])
Out[128]: 
array([[[1, 2],
        [3, 4]]])
In [129]: _.shape
Out[129]: (1, 2, 2)
```

What I wrote about `concatenate` with matching dimensions still applies.  For example, create a 'empty' with the right shape, `(0,2,2)` and expand `b` to `(1,2,2)`.

```
In [130]: np.concatenate((np.zeros((0,2,2),int),b[None,...]),axis=0)
Out[130]: 
array([[[1, 2],
        [3, 4]]])
```

`b[None,...]` is (1,2,2), so there's no need to concatenate anything.

There is a `np.stack` which adds a dimension to all input arrays and then concatenates.  But I don't see how that can apply here.  The only thing that can be added to a (2,2) array with stack is another (2,2) array.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of making it work:

```
# start with zero layers of the right shape:
>>> a = np.empty((0, 2, 2), int)
>>> a
array([], shape=(0, 2, 2), dtype=int64)
>>> b = np.arange(1, 5).reshape(2, 2)
>>> b
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
# use np.r_ instead of append the spec string '0,3,1' means concatenate
# along axis 0, make everything 3D, operands with fewer than 3
# get 1 axis added on the left
>>> np.r_['0,3,1', a, b]
array([[[1, 2],
        [3, 4]]])
```